# ¿Cómo limito los caracteres a varios elementos de una tabla, a la vez?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla que se actualiza por si sola: a medida que el usuario va insertando datos en ella.
Lo que quiero es que el usuario no pueda teclear más de 40 caracteres en las celdas (los elementos td de la tabla); para ello utilicé el siguiente código:

**HTML**

```
<td class="lon" onKeyPress="long(event)" contenteditable></td>
<td class="lon" onKeyPress="long(event)" contenteditable></td>
<td class="lon" onKeyPress="long(event)" contenteditable></td>
```

**JS**

```
function long(e) {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName('lon')[0].innerText.length === 40) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

El código parece funcionar correctamente, sin embargo el problema es evidente: y es que este código solo funciona para el elemento que se encuentra en la primera posición del arreglo, y si quiero escribir en las demás celdas entonces no podré hacerlo. Para ello traté de realizar lo siguiente:

**JS**

```
function long(e) {
            if ($(this).text().length === 40) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Sin embargo no me funciona y no me explico el porqué. Quisiera saber que opción tengo para realizar esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el primer ejemplo de JS, cambia **document.getElementsByClassName('lon')[0]** por **e.target**, ya que **target** hace referencia al elemento que genera el evento. Quedaría así:

```
function long(e) {
    if (e.target.innerText.length === 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```